# Stop a macro if rows generated in a structured table repeat X number of times

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a workbook containing a Summary sheet and 200 numbered sheets that the user fills in one after the other.
The following macro checks about 125 cell values on every numbered sheet, and fills in the Summary, one line per numbered sheet.
If a numbered sheet hasnt been used yet, the macro fills in every column from column D to column DV with the minus sign "-" and goes on to check every numbered sheet one after the other till there's no more to check.

Is there a way to set it so that if an arbitrary number (let's say 10 lines) of the newly generated lines contain only the minus sign "-" from D to DV (Iw,4 to Iw, 126), then the macro would reach its end as it means all the remaining numbered sheets aren't used yet?

```
Sub SummaryMacro()
Dim Sh As Worksheet
Range("B2:L1000").ClearContents
Iw = 2  ' Index Write
For Each Sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    If Sh.Name = "Summary" Then GoTo EndConsolidation
    Cells(Iw, 1).Select
With Selection
    .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & Sh.Name & "'" & "!" & "A1", TextToDisplay:="Go to"
End With
    Cells(Iw, 2) = Sh.Name
    If Sh.Range("D8") = "" Then
    Cells(Iw, 3) = "-"
    Else
    Cells(Iw, 3) = Sh.Range("D8")
    End If
    
   'Here the rest of the process (Iw, 4 till Iw, 125)
   'The process also includes a few variations:
   
   'Something like 20 of those with various text
   If Sh.CheckBoxes("Check Box 1").Value = 1 Then Cells(Iw, 40) = "Declared" Else Cells(Iw, 40) = "-"  
   
   'Something like 30 of those with various text
    If Sh.Range("H33") = "Issued" Then
    Cells(Iw, 42) = "-"
   Else
   Cells(Iw, 42) = Sh.Range("H33")
   End If
    
    'But all in all they are mostly like that
    If Sh.Range("C134") = "" Then
    Cells(Iw, 126) = "-"
    Else
    Cells(Iw, 126) = Sh.Range("C134")
    End If
   
    Iw = Iw + 1
EndConsolidation:
Next Sh

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this code to your For loop at the end:

```
   If (WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("D" & Iw & ":DV" & Iw), "-") = 123) Then
     Cntr = Cntr + 1  'Blank sheet found
   Else
     Cntr = 0  'Not blank - Restart counter
   End If
   
   If (Cntr = 10) Then Exit For
```

This counts the number of - in your row and if it equals 123 (D-DV) then it increments the counter otherwise it clears the counter. When Cntr reaches 10 it exits the loop.

HTH

Comment: Your answer seems as simple and elegant as i wished it to end up being, maybe it's a bit early in the day but i can't figure out where to paste that bit, I believe i tried everywhere and can't get it to work, could you point that out please? I think I tried it before, between and after  Iw = Iw + 1 ,    EndConsolidation:   and   Next Sh to no avail

Comment: Nevermind, I didnt put it before  Iw = Iw + 1 and as soon as I did, worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

When I have something like this I `Dim` a Boolean variable (perhaps call it isPopulated) which only gets switched to true when one of the cells has a value to act on. Then for your case after 10 (or however many you choose) lines, insert an `If isPopulated = False Then Exit For` to skip the remaining sheets.

EDIT; another idea I just had for you - if all the cells you're checking are supposed to have numeric values then you could use the below;

```
If Not WorksheetFunction.Concat(Range("D8"), Range("C134"), etc) Like "*#*" Then
'Code here to skip this and remaining sheets.
```

Obviously you'd need to add the relevant ranges inside the `concat()` brackets. What that will do is join the contents of those cells together, then check the result for any numbers `"*#*"` (you could also check for any letters using `"*?*"`). That gives you a one-code-line answer to the basic question 'is this sheet populated or not'.

Comment: Hey thanks for your input, the values aren't numerical sadly. Have a great day

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure it's a bad idea to terminate the macro prematurely, based on such an imprecise criterion as the number of "empty" sheets in series. If data starts again on the 11th, 15th or 30th sheet, then you will not process it, you will lose it.

Your macro is not very complex, it shouldn't take longer than a few seconds. For modern Excel, 25K cells are very few

Your code can be shortened a little, simplified. After all, you know all the addresses of the cells that you need to check on each sheet, you enter them in the macro code sequentially, right? Write them on one line separated by commas and put them in a constant.

After that, the whole code will become much shorter:

```
Sub SummaryMacro()
Const REQUIRED_CELLS_ADDRESS As String = "D8,...<all other source cells>...,B6"
Const SUM_SHEETNAME As String = "Summary"

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wsSum As Worksheet
Dim rCell As Range
Dim oTargetCell As Range
Dim oSumCell As Range
Dim aAddress As Variant
Dim i As Integer
    aAddress = Split(REQUIRED_CELLS_ADDRESS, ",")
    Set wsSum = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(SUM_SHEETNAME)
    wsSum.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0).ClearContents
    Set oTargetCell = wsSum.Range("A1")
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> SUM_SHEETNAME Then
            Set oTargetCell = oTargetCell.Offset(1, 0)
            wsSum.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=oTargetCell, Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & ws.Name & "'" & "!" & "A1", TextToDisplay:="Go to"
            oTargetCell.Resize(1, 123).Value = "-"
            Set oSumCell = oTargetCell.Offset(0, 1)
            oSumCell.Value = ws.Name
            For i = LBound(aAddress) To UBound(aAddress)
                Set rCell = ws.Range(aAddress(i))
                Set oSumCell = oSumCell.Offset(0, 1)
                If Not IsEmpty(rCell) Then oSumCell.Value2 = rCell.Value2
            Next i
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

**Update** Everyone knows that working with an array in RAM is much faster than working with sheet cells. Therefore, the outer loop - iterating over the sheets of the book - remains the same, but we change the code inside the loop in this way:

```
Sub SummaryMacro()
Const SUM_SHEETNAME As String = "Summary"
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wsSum As Worksheet
Dim oTargetCell As Range
Dim aResData As Variant
    aAddress = Split(REQUIRED_CELLS_ADDRESS, ",")
    Set wsSum = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(SUM_SHEETNAME)
    wsSum.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0).ClearContents
    Set oTargetCell = wsSum.Range("A1")
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> SUM_SHEETNAME Then
            Set oTargetCell = oTargetCell.Offset(1, 0)
            wsSum.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=oTargetCell, Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & ws.Name & "'" & "!" & "A1", TextToDisplay:="Go to " & ws.Name
            aResData = validateData(ws.Range("A1:L140").Value2) ' Or  "D8:C134" or any other
            oTargetCell.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, UBound(aResData) + 1).Value = aResData
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

The main trick is hidden in this line `aResData = validateData(ws.Range("A1:L140").Value2)`
We call our function and pass it as a parameter an array of cell values ​​from the entire next sheet. Further work on analysis and processing will be carried out with the elements of this array. However, this is not the whole trick.

```
The validateData() function is very simple and looks like this:
Function validateData(aD As Variant) As Variant
    validateData = validateValues(aD(1, 5), aD(2, 8), aD(3, 1), aD(2, 11), _
       ........ , _
       aD(111, 3), aD(112, 8), aD(123, 9), aD(126, 10))
End Function
```

In other words, we select from the entire large array of aD (the name is deliberately made short, because in this function it will have to be repeated 123 times) only those values ​​that need to be analyzed and we pass on to the next function. Despite the seeming simplicity, this is the most time-consuming part - you need to select from the sheet all cells "D8", "C134", etc. and write down their coordinates (row, column) as numbers `aD(4,8)`, `aD(3,134)`, etc.
Perhaps can help in this the mode R1C1 of displaying the sheet. Or some kind of helper function that will be used when preparing the code (not when executing - we agreed that we will no longer access cells for get values ​​or for `.Row` and `.Column` properties!)

What will the validateData() function get? A long one-dimensional array `aData(0 To 122)` of cell values ​​in the listed order. That is, as many values ​​as there are cells to be filled in the Summary row for this sheet.

The last trick is the process of processing values. It would seem that we have gained nothing from all these transformations. But you claim that there are three groups of checks - for an empty value, for a boolean value (checkbox) and for text lines. This is how it is handled:

```
Function validateValues(ParamArray aData() As Variant) As Variant
Dim i As Variant
Dim aResult As Variant
    ReDim aResult(LBound(aData) To UBound(aData))
    For i = LBound(aData) To UBound(aData)
        Select Case i
            Case 1, 5, 7, 9 ' Checking cells empty / value
                aResult(i) = IIf(aData(i) = "", "-", aData(i))
            Case 4, 6, 10   ' Checking cells boolean True / "not True" (False or blank)
                aResult(i) = IIf(aData(i), "Declared", "-")
            Case 0, 3, 8    ' Checking cells string "Issued" / other
                aResult(i) = IIf(aData(i) = "Issued", "-", aData(i))
            Case 2, 91, 118 ' Checking cells string "Pending" / other
                aResult(i) = IIf(aData(i) = "Issued", "-", aData(i))
            Case Else   ' In a real macro, this line is not needed, it will never be executed because all the cells of the array are already listed above, this is useful only for debugging while all conditions will be written
                aResult(i) = "-"
                Debug.Print "Cell #" & i & " not processed yet"
        End Select
    Next i
    validateValues = aResult
End Function
```

And now - again, in just one call! - we write a whole row of results:

```
oTargetCell.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, UBound(aResData) + 1).Value = aResData
```

I am sure that these tricks will reduce the time it takes to form the summary sheet many times over. Please try this and let me know if it gets better?

Comment: It's barely within my reach but i think there's something I can do with what you propose, maybe it's worth expanding what my macro does, if you'd like to you could check the updated code which will show that it's not entirely sequential but I hope i could mix methods to improve it still

Comment: @CMProjetIDF Oh, I see - not only empty cells are checked, but also the presence of certain words similar to "Issued" and checkboxes that do not save their values ​​on the sheet? Do checkboxes really not store their values ​​in worksheet cells using the `Cell Link` property? Find the author of the template for this workbook, beat him up and force him to remake it all so that it is convenient not only for users, but also for the programmer. If you can't handle it yourself - call me (I have my own bill with these designers)

Comment: To clarify, most of the time I need the cell content or if cell is empty to fill in with "-" but sometimes I need to output a specific string depending on cell/checkbox string/value. I don't clearly see how to adapt your code for that second part and how to order things as it can be ten of the first then one of the other, so on and so forth, but I feel that your code is not too far off my needs. I wonder about time gain if i were to upgrade, so far my code takes about 1mn30 on a pretty good computer and my users having to use the macro often, it's not super impressive time-wise...

Comment: Guilty, I'm the one who made the template! For checkboxes i got a control zone with the values of the checkboxes linked (True/False) it's just that the output format can't just turn up those values. when something is false or blank its always outputing "-" on the summary but when something is true it has to output different strings

Comment: There are three types of data in the workbook: cells containing either text or numbers that the user fills in, checkboxes and drop down lists with text.

Comment: "I'm the one who made the template" Oops! Sorry :-) It is a pity that in your question you did not immediately tell how difficult everything is. However, in this case, your question would be immediately closed on the grounds that the answers will not be useful to many users, but only to you. Let's be clear - did you show the flag analysis to illustrate the complexity of the raw data? Or are you really processing these values? I got one idea, but this will only work with data, not controls. (And yes - we will not kick the designer)

Comment: As i wanted to keep things straightforward, i simplified the question as much as I could and in that way got a pretty straight answer to it, in that sense i think it served its purpose and will be useful to other users. I really am processing the data after i manage to output it in the required format. whats your idea like?

Comment: @CMProjetIDF I thought about general code speeding up. If you look at your sample, it is clear that almost a third of it consists of endless direct references to the cells of the sheets, all these Cells (Iw, 40) and Sh.Range ("H33"). It has long been known that reading all values ​​of a rectangular range into a rectangular array is comparable in time to reading one cell. No, a comment is a bad place to show an idea. I will now modify my answer to show the structure of the code. Pls wait

Comment: Can't move to chat not enough rep... Sir, your answer looked like dark magic at first but I actually understand pretty much all of it and if it works as intended that would be genius, one thing I still unsure about: the case number is determined by the order i populate ValidateData, correct?

Comment: @CMProjetIDF (I don't remember at what level of reputation the chat will become available to you, but I hope that soon - comments are not a very good place for discussing subtle details.) Yes, you're right - in the order they should appear in the Summary line, cell by cell, from index 0 to largest 122/ And this index used in Case statement.

Comment: I need five more points for the ability to move to chat, next time. Ok it all seems super clear, I'm seriously pumped up for this and am going to work on that asap. Might take a bit but I swear i'll come back to you when it's done

Comment: I'll be waiting around here - I'm really wondering if you can manage not to interrupt the macro after a dozen blank sheets.

Comment: Quick update and a question! So far so good, I hope it's not gonna get too heavy by the end but so far it's blazing fast, strong emphasis on the blazing! Between the hyperlink and the start of validateData I would like to get a column with  the cell outputing ws.Name but i realize i dont understand cell offset well enough to add that, could you point out how to make it happen? Then it's a matter of keeping on going through all the index and case statement but I'm incredibly positive about it!

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was another design mistake - a separate hyperlink with the universal text "Get out!" ... no, there was "Go to", but the meaning is the same and - in a separate column, the sheet name. Therefore, I combined them in one cell `TextToDisplay:="Go to " & ws.Name`. No problem! Just insert line  `oTargetCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = ws.Name` and increase offset in `oTargetCell.Offset(0, 2).Resize(1, UBound(aResData) + 1).Value = aResData`

Comment: The second parameter in OFFSET() is the number of columns by which we need to deviate from the given cell (sometimes the whole range, but this is rarely used - it is difficult to understand). That is, OFFSET(0,1) is the next cell to the right, OFFSET(0,2) is one column further, etc. The main beauty of this notation is the "base" cell, from which the counting starts, remains in the same place (in our case, in column A). And with the next statement `Set oTargetCell = oTargetCell.Offset(1, 0)` we will move it down one line in the same column A

Comment: I was close, i did find oTargetCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = ws.Name but everything was in diagonal, looked beautiful but useless. Didn't understand that I had to increase the offset of the other line! Ok, next time I write it'll be to show the final results

Comment: You were moving very fast! I was sure that correct cell addressing in `validateData()` and `Select Case i` would take much longer. I am waiting for the final results - an estimate of the running time of the old program and the new one.

Comment: It's pretty done, is there a way to add a few more fringe boolean cases with special outputs in some way: Case 24, 25, 26, and many more...
                aResult(i) = IIf(aData(i), "O", "-") that works perfect but then if i add
            Case 4
                aResult(i) = IIf(aData(i) = "Abandonned", "-")
            Case 5
                aResult(i) = IIf(aData(i) = "F", "-")
            Case 6
                aResult(i) = IIf(aData(i) = "M", "-")
            Case 37, 40, 43, 46, 49
                aResult(i) = IIf(aData(i) = "Obtained", "-")   its obviously not working

Comment: This is very, very strange! Debug - Сompilе VBA project doesn't show any syntax errors?  I'm afraid of one trouble for which I am to blame. I was not persistent enough when I warned that the cell array starts at element zero. Perhaps you missed this and specified all indices starting from 1 in the `Select Case` statement? If so, do not rush to redo all 123 indexes, just change the title of this instruction to `Select Case i+1`

Comment: So every base is covered, how can i lastly use the replace function efficiently to replace an output word for the sign "-", i got two cells in the template that have to show "Unknown" and "Missing" which i'd like to convert to "-" after generating the new table

Comment: you were very clear and index does start at zero, as do case statements. If i do Case 0, 8,...       aResult(i) = IIf(aData(i) = "", "-", aData(i))
Case 24, 25,              aResult(i) = IIf(aData(i), "O", "-") it works and outputs case 24 and 25 with replacement text "O" but if i add
Case 1         aResult(i) = IIf(aData(i) = "Abandonned", "-")  it says argument not optionnal and if i write Case 1         aResult(i) = IIf(aData(i) = "Abandonned", "-", aData(i)) it does output but only true or false, not replacement text

Comment: Yes, in the first version the third argument of the `IIF()` function is really missing - for the case "else".  There is a condition `aData(i) = "Abandonned"`, result for TRUE  `"-"` also present, but not value for FALSE when `aData(i) <> "Abandonned"`. Can you set breakpoint on this line and watch real value of aData(1)? May be it cell with any checkbox status and it really is TRUE or FALSE, not text?

Answer (score 0):

Add this code before your For loop ends

```
Dim counter As Integer
Dim previousRowBlank As Boolean
counter = 0
previousRowBlank = True

 'count if all the 123 cells contain - string
    If (WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("Summary").Range("D" & Iw & ":DV" & Iw), "-") = 123) Then
        If (counter = 0) Then
            counter = counter + 1
            previousRowBlank = True
        Else
            If (previousRowBlank = True) Then
            counter = counter + 1
            End If
        End If
    Else
        previousRowBlank = False
        counter = 0
    End If
    
    'assuming you want to exit when 10 consecutive rows are blank
    If (counter = 10) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

Comment: Same answer as i gave Retiredgeek, yours seems also simple and elegant but i can't figure out where to paste that bit, I believe i tried everywhere and can't get it to work, could you point that out please? I think I tried it before, between and after Iw = Iw + 1 , EndConsolidation: and Next Sh to no avail

Comment: Made Retiredgeek bit of code to work but am still interested in finding out why i couldnt get yours to function, if you don't mind

Comment: Add these lines to the start of the code : Dim counter As Integer
Dim previousRowBlank As Boolean
counter = 0
previousRowBlank = True    ... ..Add the rest of the code just before Iw = Iw + 1